# Change the color of several GridView cells in one command

Tags: asp.net, gridview

How can I change the `BackColor` of several cells at once? Instead of writing code like this:

```
e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = Color.Azure;
e.Row.Cells[3].BackColor = Color.Azure;
e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = Color.Azure;
e.Row.Cells[5].BackColor = Color.Azure;
e.Row.Cells[6].BackColor = Color.Azure;
```

Maybe there is a command to color several cells at once, like:

```
e.Row.Cells[from 2 to 6].BackColor = Color.Azure;
```

I do not want to change the color of the whole row, just the cells from 2 to 6.

Comment: are you looking to change the color of whole row? then you can set it like this: `e.Row.BackColor = Color.Azure;`

Comment: no @Knvn I want to color a certain amount of cells in a row f.e. we have 10 cells in a row and I want to color 5 of them using one command?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the range that you want to color, you could do it in a for loop.

```
for (int i = 1;i < 7;i++)
{
e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = Color.Azure
}
```

Not the most elegant but it will do the job.

Comment: It did the job! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a extension method.

```
public static class GridViewRowExtensions
{
    public static void ChangeBackColorOfCells(this GridViewRow row, int[] cells)
    {
        foreach(int i in cells)
        {
            row.Cells[i].BackColor = Color.Azure;
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you want to change the background color of the cells 1, 3 and 4 you can do like this:

```
e.Row.ChangeBackColorOfCells(new[] {1,3,4});
```

**Note:** This approach is preferred only, if you want to change the color of non-linear cells and using it on multiple places of your application. Otherwise, you can put the loop as suggested by **Lareau** on the `RowDataBound` handler itself.